# ImpactJS and astar pathfinder

Tags: javascript, html, impactjs

Using this library: https://github.com/hurik/impact-astar-for-entities

I can get a path to print, but as soon as I do followPath in my "monster" entity, the sprite disappears?!

[image: http://prntscr.com/1eydqf]

What could I be doing wrong?

```
    update: function() {
        // Update it every 2 seconds
        if(this.pathTimer.delta() > 0) {
            // Get the path to the player
            this.getPath(416, 302, true, ['EntityMonster'], []);

            this.pathTimer.reset();
        }

        // Walk the path
        this.followPath(this.speed);

        this.parent();
    },
```

Comment: Can you show us what's in `this.followPath();`?